# Painting a JPanel hides menu

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel on which custom painting is performed which may take upto 15 seconds.

[image]

The problem is that when I click on a menu while the while the JPanel is being painted, the painting is being done over the menu and the options are not visible. ( See the distorted text in picture )

[image]

If I click on the menu after the painting is completed, there is no unwanted behavior but when I move the mouse pointer onto a different menu, the same thing happens again.
For example, after the completion of painting, if I click on 'Applications', no side effect occurs but when I move the mouse pointer onto 'Help', the previously described behavior is exhibited.
How can this be avoided?

I am performing the painting outside the paintComponent() method in a separate thread:

```
public class RandomIFSPanel extends JPanel {

  RandomIFSPanelRenderer randomIFSPanelRenderer;

 @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        try {
            randomIFSPanelRenderer.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
randomIFSPanelRenderer = new RandomIFSPanelRenderer();
   randomIFSPanelRenderer.start();
}

    class RandomIFSPanelRenderer extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
                Graphics g=getGraphics();
             g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
               g.drawLine........
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your threading may well be the issue here - if you don't do all painting on the EDT then you're asking for trouble / quirks such as this. If you use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, does the problem still remain?

Comment: `Graphics g=getGraphics();` is another part of the problem.  You should consider replacing the entire painting surface for a `BufferedImage` (displayed in a `JLabel`) and shift the long running work to a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @berry120 If i use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(randomIFSPanelRenderer) instead of  randomIFSPanelRenderer.start(), the window is becoming un responsive on resizing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The entire painting process takes time and I want it to be done in real time i.e. I want the user to see the updated image as the pixels are computed and  painted one by one.

Comment: *"I want it to be done in real time"*  I want a flying pony, but it doesn't mean I'll get one.  The 'real time' aspect is not something that the Java GUI architecture can support.  Follow the strategy outlined in my 1st comment using a `BufferedImage`, every 100 or so updates, call `repaint()` on the label.  If JRE is not busy, those changes will be rendered, but if it is busy doing other GUI updates, the call might be coalesced with other calls to repaint.  All what you are doing is not going to achieve 'real time' updates.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been said about the Event Dispatch Thread:

- Are you calling the paintComponent() method directly? It is "safer" to call repaint().
- Is it possible to buffer the image, paint it and then setting on your panel when paintComponent() is called?

Comment: When the user clicks the 'Draw' button, I am calling randomIFSPanel.repaint(). RandomIFSPanel is the black and white portion of the window which is displaying the drawing.

Comment: The entire painting takes a lot of time depending on the values input by the user. I want to update the image with each pixel as it is computed in real time. So, it is not possible to buffer the image.

Comment: Maybe buffering the image and showing results every 100ms or so. If the problem doesn't disappear, try calling repaint() in your frame.

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't start a thread in `paintComponent()` method, because `paintComponent()` could be invoked many times by `repaint()`. It will probably happen that new threads are started while previous ones are not termintated.

Second, if you want the menu be painted normally, try to add `super.paintComponent(g)` at the beginning of `paintComponent()`.

Third, `Graphics g = getGraphics();` why not just use `graphics`? Since Graphics objects are changing, you can't assume next painting is doing in the same old Graphics object.

Comment: Though I haven't stated it in my Question, I am first stopping the previous  randomIFSPanelRenderer Thread before starting the new one. I have modified my code in the question to reflect it. I did not understand what you meant by saying 'why not just use graphics'. Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Adding super.paintComponent(g) at the beginning of paintComponent() didn't work.

Comment: @Ranjith-SR2GF You have `graphics` defined in `paintComponent()` method. This is what you should use, rather than call `getGraphics()`. Again, even you stopped the previous thread, it is still not good to create and start a new thread in `paintComponent()` method. How can you make sure the previous thread is finished when called again.

Comment: @Ranjith-SR2GF Instead of creating threads within the method, you should create a thread outside and call `repaint()` in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

- don't to use Thread will block EDT, not the all of events could be visible on the screen, in some case only 1st. and last, use Swing Timer instead
- don't to create any Object, FileIO, Thread, etc. inside paintComponent , nor unsafe inside try - catch - finally block
- create any Objects before, put that to the array and inside paintComponent to loop inside arrays of finalized Objects
- post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about painting, all Object should be stored as local variable (for real, any answer to your question about quadratic fading and zoomout)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have a thread running inside a paintComponent method. I would have the thread outside the paint method.

Comment: The thread required the Graphics object of the JPanel, so I need to use statements like getGraphics.drawXYZ() which can't be done if I have that thread outside the paint method.